# Using `novalidate` submits the form with an invalid input

Tags: javascript, html

I do not want a non url to be submitted, and I am using `type=url` in my form input class. However, using the `type=url` attribute causes some default validation in chrome which renders a less than ideal validation popup.

I have been able to block the default validation by using the below block, and `novalidate` in my form tag

```
validate.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (input.checkValidity() !== true) {
    input.className = 'false';
    input.classList.remove('true');
    errorMessage.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    input.className = 'true';
    input.classList.remove('false');
    errorMessage.style.display = 'none';
  }
})
```

However, when I use `novalidate` in my form class, it causes the form to submit when a value is invalid, throwing an error message.

Any ideas on how I can stop this from submitting? When I remove novalidate, the form will not submit but the default validation is thrown.

Code sample to produce the default validation is here

```
<form id="Submit">
  <div>
    <input id="search" type="url" name="url" placeholder="Test">
  </div>

  <div class=" input-field second-wrap ">
    <button id="button " value="press " type="submit ">
      SEARCH
    </button>
  </div>
  
  <p id="errorMessage ">uhoh</p>

</form>
```